# Output precision of `writeln()` for floating-point numbers

Tags: chapel

Using `writef()`, I can control the output precision of a floating-point number, for example:

```
writef( "%20.15dr\n", 1.0 / 3.0 );      // 0.333333333333333
```

but if I use `writeln()` for convenience, the number is output with 6 digits:

```
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );                   // 0.333333
```

Is there possibly a way to control the default output precision of floating-point numbers for `writeln()`..? (e.g., via some environment variable?)

For comparison, some languages output 15 digits and some 6 digits by default, so the result seems to vary depending on languages (or compilers).

```
# python2
print 1.0 / 3.0      # 0.333333333333
# python3
print( 1.0 / 3.0 )   # 0.3333333333333333
# julia
println( 1.0 / 3.0 )   # 0.3333333333333333
# gfortran
print *, 1.0d0 / 3.0d0   # 0.33333333333333331
# swift
print( 1.0 / 3.0 )       # 0.333333333333333
# nim
echo( 1.0 / 3.0 )       # 0.3333333333333333
# g++
cout << 1.0 / 3.0 << endl;   # 0.333333
# d (dmd)
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );      # 0.333333
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [iostyle](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.iostyle) and [_set_style()](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.channel._set_style) :

```
writeln(100.0/3.0);   // 33.3333

stdout.lock();
stdout._set_style(new iostyle(precision=10));
stdout.unlock();

writeln(100.0/3.0);   // 33.33333333
```

You can also pass other things to `new iostyle()`, for example:

```
precision=10, realfmt=0          // like %.10g in C:  33.33333333      (default)
precision=10, realfmt=1          // like %.10f in C:  33.3333333333
precision=10, realfmt=2          // like %.10e in C:  3.3333333333e+01
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly I was looking for (plus a lot of additional options... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is.  In Chapel, I/O is performed on *channels*.  Each channel has an I/O style (represented by a record of type `iostyle`) which specifies how values are printed to that channel if a more specific style is not provided within the read/write call itself.  A call to `writeln()` is essentially a call to `stdout.writeln()` where `stdout` is a channel whose output shows up in the console.

The following example shows how to change the I/O style of stdout ([Try it Online](https://tio.run/##nZExDsIwDEX3nuKPsFAq1AlxACYGDlBFrUsslaRKXCpOX0IakBiQKB4s2Un@83dqrXrqpinP0Ts2ArHw0thBMHg2F7B4NNSqoZNwcO8ICyMbHQt1ZoVis0WOXcjrfZYFYu1ICUHB0IjjKemPLDr0ekc1e7YGtkVR/kK6KZc0DlGSbaxWb6lDUb7QWpkLvawG04MniGYfHy40ms0ym8qTVDMy5sSaFzuvUzT9Q/hpnY68WEeR8fllyjRpCmtqwvV5a7mnpHk8nWO5Dtgvwzxjmh4)):

```
// print to stdout using its default style                                                
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );

// create a new IO style with a precision of 15                                   
var style = new iostyle(precision=15);

// change stdout to use this new style                                          
stdout._set_style(style);

// print using the new style                                                    
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );

// restore the default style and print once more                                
stdout._set_style(defaultIOStyle());
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );
```

where the output is:

```
0.333333
0.333333333333333
0.333333
```

Note that it isn't safe to change the style of a channel in parallel code without locking it first.  Since the example above is completely serial, it's OK, but in the context of a larger, potentially parallel, program, the better approach would be to lock the channel before setting its style, as follows ([Try it Online](https://tio.run/##pVHNbsIwDL7nKXwsF7oKcZp4AE4c9gAoSg2xljlV4lDt6buQpqBJmwSbD5b8k@/HMVYP6KapbWEIxALiIUrvk0CKxGcgidDjSScnefDpEJ4MNQYSdNxAt36BFjY5r16VyowmoBYEDYwj7A8VfySxuTcENBTJM/gTdNtHmC46VIxdgSRfquYGteu2C7XVfMbFajadIoJYiuXhk0bVDLN23rw3maCWx4hynBWUfJ8kXlbV7fDzucXiXxQ8dO6AUXzAwvH9SzX3VYVng/Bx3fq350qxP7yVcvWT/V/EXmOavgA)):

```
// print to stdout using its default style                                                
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );

// create a new IO style with a precision of 15                                   
var style = new iostyle(precision=15);

// change stdout to use this new style                                          
stdout.lock();
stdout._set_style(style);
stdout.unlock();

// print using the new style                                                    
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );

// restore the default style and print once more                                
stdout.lock();
stdout._set_style(defaultIOStyle());
stdout.unlock();
writeln( 1.0 / 3.0 );
```

Chapel's online documentation has more information about [I/O styles](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#i-o-styles), the fields of the [`iostyle` record](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.iostyle), and [locking of channels](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#about-io-channel-synchronization).

Comment: Thanks very much for more examples! And I have one question... For a small test code (with a single file), is it usually okay to just put "stdout._set_style(new iostyle(precision=10));" at the top of that source file, even if it performs "forall" later in the code, without stdout.lock/unlock? (I.e., I will not change such IO style during the parallel execution.)

Comment: I believe that should be safe.  Unless I'm mistaken, the locking should only be necessary if the style is changed while other tasks are using the channel simultaneously.